# How to test properties passed from one view controller to another in Unit tests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller

My project commonly passes properties from one UIViewController to another within the perpareForSegue:sender: method. I am very new to testing so this may be a silly question but I could not find an answer online.

I want to test that the property passed from UIViewController A is not nil in UIViewController B when viewDidLoad is called in B. How can I test this using unit tests without integrating my tests in application code?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**:

I have been keeping at it a bit. [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623442/mark-w) seems to have had a similar situation and found that instantiating a Storyboard segue within the unit test allows him to call performSegue. However, it does not seem to pass the values from one view controller to the next. In the example below, the log shows null in the debug window:

```
UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier"
                                                           source:sourceVC
                                                      destination:destinationVC
                                                   performHandler:^{
}];
[sourceVC prepareForSegue:segue sender:self];
NSLog(@"%@", destinationVC.managedObjectContext);
```

The performHandler is intentionally left blank. Using nil raises an exception. Looks like we are getting close!

Comment: +1. This sort of test seems pretty important to have kicking around.